# Is sharing the Membership Provider with other devs a security risk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hope this is a good place for this, but I am looking to be safe while sharing my ASP MVC project. If a page was designed with a membership provider is is possible to share this project with out leaking information about your membership provider? From my understanding it would be very difficult for another developer to work on the project without this piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be about keeping files secret for security reasons, not for intellectual property protection reasons. You should not be worried about sharing your files, especially your membership provider code. If you have custom built a membership provider, then it is especially important that you let other people review it for potential security flaws. If you have used the standard membership, such as Identity or SimpleMembership, then there is no benefit in hiding that fact.

In practical terms in any ASP.NET MVC project I have worked on, the membership aspect is so deeply coupled with the rest of the code it would be next to impossible to remove it without rendering the project useless to your collaborators, or putting an overly large integration burden onto yourself for changes that are made by them.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes I am using the standard membership provider. You hit one of my main concerns right on the head. I assumed that it was nearly impossible to decouple this code and still have it runable. I was merely worried that by providing some of this code it could be seen as a security issue. I know this probably shows my ignorance on the topic of how all of this is implemented.

Comment: No ignorance shown. Your code will show your data structure, so that means that you would be more at risk (its easier to attack) if you did things like allow SQL injection through forms, query strings etc. It will also show any flaws you have openly. However by sharing it you are hoping that all those potential flaws will be found and closed down. Only you can work out if sharing it will really help you close down any problems and make it safe.